# How to change height of a grouped tableViewCell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, row-height

I'm trying to display address as its displayed in Contact app of iPhone. so it seems i need a cell with height three times of a regular cell. as its always going to be same i just need to apply a fixed height to the code. but i don't know how to do it. my current code is

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    NSString *address = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n"@"%@ %@ %@\n"@"%@", dispAddress, dispCity, dispState, dispZip, dispCountry];
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue2 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
    }


    // Configure the cell...

        cell.detailTextLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
        cell.detailTextLabel.numberOfLines = 3; // 0 means no max.
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = address;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To set all cells to the same fixed height, in viewDidLoad or some other appropriate place, do:

```
self.tableView.rowHeight = 100;
```

To set cells to different heights based on index path, use the heightForRowAtIndexPath delegate method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if ((indexPath.section == 0) && (indexPath.row == 0))
        return 100;
    else
        return 44;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Anna, heightForRowAtIndexPath worked perfect. Thanks a lot.